# A property that is different during rendering and during preview

Tags: properties, drivers

I want some properties, like the Factor value in a Mix Shader node, be controlled by whether Blender is currently rendering or not - so that some things would look different in the Preview and in Render. Is it possible to do that? Maybe via scripted expression driver?

Comment: By preview you mean rendered viewport shading in the 3dview? I don't think that distinction can be made to the material during render. The point is that the preview should match the final render.